# android -listView -The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

this is my adapter ,I get data from my server by json then I use BaseAdapter to populate my ListView . a listview with 30 rows is made and when user reaches the end of listview , GetContacts calls again and another 30 items will be add to listView .

this is the code:

```
ListAdapter ladap;

private class GetContacts AsyncTask<Void, Void,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {    
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    Spots_tab1_json sh = new Spots_tab1_json();
    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url + page, Spots_tab1_json.GET);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataC = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = new String(c.getString("id").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                String dates = new String(c.getString("dates").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                String price = new String(c.getString("gheymat").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();
                contact.put("id", id);
                contact.put("dates", dates);
                contact.put("price", price);
                dataC.add(contact);
            }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            goterr = true;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            goterr = true;
        }
    } else {
        goterr = true;
    }
    return dataC;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (!isCancelled() && goterr == false) {
        if(ladap==null){
            ladap=new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this,result);
            lv.setAdapter(ladap);
        }else{
            ladap.addAll(result);
        }

}
```

}

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Activity activity;
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;

public ListAdapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
    super();
    this.activity = (Activity) activity;
    this.list = list;
}

public void addAll(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
    Log.v("this",result.size()+" resultsize");
    this.list = result;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public int getCount() {
    return contactList.size();
}

public void addAll(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
        if(list==null){
            list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
          }
          list.addAll(result);
          notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return contactList.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return 0;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView title,price;
    ImageView img ; 
    //RelativeLayout rl; 
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

        item = contactList.get(position);
        holder.price.setText(item.get("price"));
    return convertView;
}
}
```

I myself have not got this error buy my error tracker shoes it happens alot on different devices and android versions .

there are 2 errors about this 
number 1:

```
STACK_TRACE = java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131034188, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class ir.klach.persiandesigners.MainActivity$ListAdapter)]
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1535)
at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForTap.run(AbsListView.java:2215)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3770)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

PHONE_MODEL = GT-I9070
APP_VERSION_NAME = 2.7
ANDROID_VERSION = 2.3.6
```

number 2:

```
STACK_TRACE = java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131034188, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class ir.klach.persiandesigners.MainActivity$ListAdapter)]
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1551)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:4498)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7669)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2395)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2134)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2134)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2134)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2134)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2134)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2134)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2134)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2134)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2284)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1578)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2468)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:268)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2232)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7876)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3894)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3778)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5030)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5009)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5107)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

PHONE_MODEL = GT-I9082
APP_VERSION_NAME = 2.7
ANDROID_VERSION = 4.2.2
```

Could you help me to solve the problem ?

Comment: as your logical said , " Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread "

Comment: @shayanpourvatan I'm sure , it runs on postExceute , so it runs on UI thread

Answer (score 1):

Try to add new data to list adapter data holder instead assignment new data to list adapter data holder :

```
public void addAll(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
    Log.v("this",result.size()+" resultsize");
    if(this.list == null){
       this.list = result;
    }else{
       this.list.addAll(result);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although opPostExecute works on UI thread itself. But still you are facing this problem, give a try to the following.

```
context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
   {
        @override
        public void run()
       {
           list.addAll(result);
           notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
  });
```

Hop it works for you.